# Gorm many2many invalid foreign key:

Tags: go, go-gorm

model/tag.go

```golang
type TuitionCrmTag struct {
    Id             int64     `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`                           // 自增主键
    TagId     int64     `gorm:"column:tag_id" json:"tag_id"`   
    Consultants []TuitionConsultant `gorm:"many2many:tuition_crm_consultant_tag;foreignKey:TagId;references:TagId"` // 绑定的用户
}

//CREATE TABLE `tuition_crm_tag` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '自增主键',
    `tag_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '标签 ID',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COMMENT = '标签表';
```

model/consultant.go

```golang
type TuitionConsultant struct {
    Id             int64     `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`                           // 自增主键
    ConsultantId   int64     `gorm:"column:consultant_id" json:"consultant_id"`     // 顾问ID
}


//CREATE TABLE `tuition_consultant` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '自增主键',
    `consultant_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '顾问ID',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='顾问表'
```

tuition_crm_consultant_tag.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `tuition_crm_consultant_tag` (
      `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '自增主键',
      `tag_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '标签 ID',
      `consultant_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '顾问 ID',
      `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '创建时间',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `idx_consultant_id_tag_id` (`consultant_id`,`tag_id`),
      KEY `idx_tag_id` (`tag_id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COMMENT = '顾问标签表';
```

What problem I am facing:

```
2021/04/11 20:52:47 /Users/admin/go/src/code.byted.org/h_cloud/tuition_crm_svr/model/h_basic/tuition_ctm_tag_test.go:21
[error] invalid foreign key: TagId
--- PASS: TestCreateTag (0.00s)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a many2many relationship with a foreign key? If it has a foreign key, then it _belongs to_ another model (so one to many or one to one). Just remove the foreign key part of the gorm tag.

Comment: @Christian, Thanks for your response. I wanna override the foreign key references, as you can see, the `tag` table has columns `id` and `tag_id`, which `tag_id` is the foreign key  references

Comment: Can you share the code from `tuition_ctm_tag_test.go` that is causing the error

Comment: I can't understand what you want the schema of these entities to be. Is there an entity called Tag and an entity called Consultant? And then presumably a join table between these? Because your current `TuitionCrmTag` doesn't actually have any `Tags` associated with it. You need to add `[]Tag` to make it many to many OR `Tag` to make it belong to a Tag (one-to-one).

Comment: @Christian ```func TestCreateTag(t *testing.T){
 db,_ := transaction.NewManager().GetWriteConnection()
 var tag TuitionCrmTag
 db.Preload("Consultants").Find(&tag)
}``` something just like this

Comment: @Christian Yes, that is pretty confusing naming. `TuitionCrmTag` = tag, `TuitionCrmConsultant` means consultant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231033/discussion-between-christian-and-spike-).